# Access Denied error for LinkedResource in sending mail through Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, email, windows-services

```
LinkedResource lrImage = new LinkedResource(oFile.FilePath, "image/" + oFile.FileExt.Replace(".", ""));
lrImage.ContentId = oFile.FileID.ToString();
lrImage.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
avMainView.LinkedResources.Add(lrImage);
```

i have this folder structure

```
"C:\\DwellingLIVE\\Community\\CommunityUploads\\0\\0"
```

and oFile.FileExt is "".

i have given the full permissions as Network Service and Local Service and also used the given below code as but no help.

```
public void GrantAccess(string fullPath)
{
   string adminUserName = Environment.UserName;// getting your adminUserName
   DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(fullPath);
   FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);
   ds.RemoveAccessRule(fsa);
   Directory.SetAccessControl(fullPath, ds);
}
```

> Message: "Access to the path
>   'C:\DwellingLIVE\Community\CommunityUploads\0\0' is denied." This
>   is the Exception Message

Comment: Message: "Access to the path 'C:\\DwellingLIVE\\Community\\CommunityUploads\\0\\0' is denied." This is the Exception Message

Comment: When you post a question, make sure you have spent 2 minutes trying to format it, it will help you get answers trust me. People look at your post and think well if you cant put 2 minutes formatting well i cant be bothered putting in the 10 minutes researching your problem